# How could a proxy be made with (multiple layers of) encryption?

Tags: javascript, php, html, encryption, proxy

How could I make my own proxy similar to [PHProxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/) that uses multiple layers of encryption (Like [Tor](https://www.torproject.org))? By this I mean an encrypted encryption key, which is then encrypted, etc. Where should I start? And how would I encrypt it with AES?

Comment: _"Where should I start?"_ By not trying to roll your own encryption. Use an established tool or service.

Comment: I think I'll use AES.